# JQuery Autocomplete Never Fires

Tags: html, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an html page where I am trying to link an input box to an ajax autocomplete function. The problem is the function is not being called, for either success or failure.

If I change 'autocomplete' to 'keypress' it gets called, but it's not what I'm looking for.

Here is the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search-box").autocomplete(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:52139/odata/WEB_V_CIVIC_ADDRESS?",
                data: { enteredText: +$(this).val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                ContentType: "application/json, charset=UTF-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                    $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                    $("#search-box").css("background", "#FFF");
                },
                error: function (data, xml, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert("here: " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    //To select country name
    function selectCountry(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);
        $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="frmSearch">
    <input type="text" id="search-box" placeholder="Country Name" 
autocomplete="on"/>
    <div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So like I said, the ajax function never fires. If I use 'keypress' it does, but I need it to fire for autocomplete.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you including jQuery not once, not twice, but three times?

Comment: Just trying different things in case is was the jquery that wasn't working. Yes I realize I don't need them all

Comment: m'kay, have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Ah, there we go. The browser errors showed that jquery-ui wasn't being loaded properly. Thanks  j08691!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jquery-ui wasn't being loaded properly. Thanks j08691 for the tip.